# MySQL query: select max(A) and use MAX(pkey) if multiple max(A) records exist

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I've been trying to find a solution for this problem using just 1 join. Is it possible?

table:

```
pkey | uid | A | B | C
100  | 1   | 5 | 2 | 
101  | 1   | 5 | 3 | 'should find this'
102  | 1   | 4 | 6 | 
103  | 2   | 5 | 2 | 'should find this'
104  | 3   | 2 | 7 | 
105  | 3   | 1 | 1 | 
106  | 3   | 2 | 1 | 'should find this'
```

Now i need to select records with pkey 101 and 103. I use this query to select max(B).

```
SELECT table.*
FROM (
     SELECT uid, max(A) as maxA
     FROM table
     GROUP BY uid
) as maxlog
JOIN table 
ON table.uid = maxlog.uid 
AND table.A = maxlog.maxA
```

It returns two records for uid 1 (pkey 100 and 101). How can i filter on max(B) in the same query with adding another JOIN?

Comment: Another approach:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#using_variables

Comment: If we added two more rows to table A: (104,2,5,7,''), (105,2,5,1,''). Now, which rows should be returned: pkeys 101 and 105, or pkeys 101 and 104?

Comment: i added some more records for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you want is: for each `uid`, find the `MAX(pkey)` associated with the `MAX(A)` value of `A`.

If that's what you need, try this:

```
SELECT table.*
FROM (
     SELECT uid, A, MAX(pkey) as pkey
     FROM table t
     WHERE A = (SELECT MAX(A) FROM table WHERE uid = t.uid)
     GROUP BY uid, A
) as maxlog
JOIN table 
ON maxlog.pkey = table.pkey
```

Note that, while this technically only has one `JOIN`, that's really just semantics - the `SELECT MAX(A)` subquery is, in effect, a `JOIN` (and might perform better if written as such).

Comment: Your assumptions are right. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Ok this works perfect. I actually experimented both ways:
1. with the WHERE A = (SELECT MAX(A) .....
2. with an extra max(pkey) and extra JOIN around my original query.
Turns out there's no real difference in performance. Option 1 as you suggested is much simpler in writing though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `GROUP BY` you can use a subquery `ORDER BY A DESC, pkey DESC` and `LIMIT` the result to two records:

```
select t1.pkey, t1.uid, t1.A, t1.B, t1.C
from mytable t1
inner join (select   pkey, a
            from     mytable
            order by a desc, pkey desc
            limit 2) t2
on t1.pkey = t2.pkey
;
```

This is the result:

```
| pkey | uid | A | B | C                |
|------|-----|---|---|------------------|
| 101  | 1   | 5 | 3 | should find this |
| 103  | 2   | 5 | 2 | should find this |
```

*Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/ECTRHR69773)*

Comment: This has lost the `GROUP BY uid`; was it important?

Comment: this method doesn't seem to work in any case.

Comment: still giving me the desired result, http://rextester.com/MJMFG71736  what do you mean?